# Estimate of roots of polynomial with positive, decreasing coefficients

Tags: reference-request, polynomials

I am looking for guidance about the size of roots of a polynomial $\sum a_kx^k$ where the coefficients are positive and decreasing, $0<a_{k+1}<a_k$ for each $k$. My hope is that the roots (real or complex) of such a polynomial are always bigger than one in modulus. Could someone suggest a proof (or counterexample) of this? (I'm aware of the bound on the size of the roots $1+\max a_k$ for general polynomials, but am hoping for something tighter based on the positivity or decreasing nature of the coefficients.)

More generally, I'd be interested in a reference for results about bounds of roots of polynomials based solely on their coefficients.

Comment: I see where youre going with this.  A simple substitution of the form $x=sz$ for some scaling factor $s$ will turn any polynomial in $x$ into a polynomial in $z$ with strictly decreasing coefficients. Any trick that helps you estimate the roots in $z$ will also help you estimate the roots in $x$. By similar logic you could also make a substitution (and horizontal shifts) to force the coefficients into other similar patterns, such as comparable magnitudes.

Comment: Its a little off topic, but have you heard of other bounding rules, such as Newtons bound, the Negative Inverse Sum bound, Maclaurin bounds, Cauchy bounds, Kojima, Fujiwara, Ratio Sum, etc.  They all take a maximum value of some set or sum of numbers, but some bounds are going to be smaller than others for one polynomial or another. And the aforementioned linear transformations can modify your results predictably.

Comment: Also off topic, but you might find the Lin-Bairstow method, the Dandelin-Graeffe method,  Uspensky's Root isolation method, Sturm's method, Vincents method, and the fixed point iteration Laguerre's method interesting. All of which apply specifically to polynomials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may wish to consider the following review and the references cited therein for the general question.

Reviewed Works:

Analytic Theory of Polynomials by Qazi Ibadur Rahman, Gerhard Schmeisser;

Complex Polynomials by Terry Sheil-Small

Review by: Kenneth B. Stolarsky
The American Mathematical Monthly
Vol. 112, No. 7 (Aug. - Sep., 2005), pp. 664-671

Comment: I checked out the references. It looks like the  Enestrom-Kakeya
theorem,mentioned in all three that you listed, is the way to go. Many thanks for the pointers.